# How do I configure PAM authentication to combine password + OTP token

Tags: openvpn, pam

I'm trying to implement PAM authentication of an OpenVPN server for users stored in an IPA server. My use case requires PAM authentication as opposed to LDAP authentication.

In testing, a user configured in IPA to authenticate with password only can successfully authenticate. But authentication fails when the IPA user is configured to authenticate with password + OTP token.

As described in the link @  https://sourceforge.net/p/openvpn/mailman/message/35969399/

I configured /etc/pam.d/openvpn like this:

```
   auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
   auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so otp_in_password
   auth        required      pam_deny.so
   account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
   account     required      pam_permit.so
```

But authentication fails with the IPA log showing invalid credentials.

I read elsewhere to configure SSSD to accept 2FA value as part of the password field because OpenVPN has no way to ask multiple prompts for PAM conversation. But I'm not sure how to make that configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

The key was using a later version of sssd. In version 2.0.x, authentication prompting configuration became available – re: https://sssd.io/docs/design_pages/prompting_configuration.html

Unfortunately my OpenVPN instance was running on Centos 7.8 which only supports up to version 1.16. So I spun up a Centos 8 VM with sssd version 2.2.3 already loaded. Fedora 29 or higher would also work.

On the Centos 8 VM I installed & configured openVPN and free-ipa-client. I then configured sssd to combine password & OTP token into one value.

```
vi /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
```

Add the following sections to the bottom of the file:

```
[prompting/password]
password_prompt = Please enter LDAP password:

[prompting/2fa]
single_prompt = True
first_prompt = Please enter LDAP password + OTP token value:
```

Change the prompting words as needed. It really only shows up when testing from  the cli. But most importantly I learned after many hours that **BOTH** sections are required in the order shown.

Next, configure pam.d by editing the file used for the OpenVPN service – in my case the file is named openvpn

```
vi /etc/pam.d/openvpn
```

Add the following:

```
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so
auth        required      pam_deny.so
account     [default=bad  success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so
```

Restart sssd and openvpn

```
systemctl restart sssd
systemctl restart openvpn-server@server
```

I also followed the steps descibed in the link @ https://sourceforge.net/p/openvpn/mailman/message/35969399/ to configure FreeIPA.

To test locally:

- Configure a user in FreeIPA to use password only. In my case the user
  id is test5
- Switch to a local user on the server that does not have sudo
  privileges
- `su testuser`
- Now attempt to switch to the ipa user
- `su test5`
- You should be prompted - *Please enter LDAP password:*
- Confirm you can log in with password only and then exit back to
  testuser
- Now configure the user (test5) in FreeIPA to use password + OTP
- Create a token in FreeIPA for user test5
- Attempt to switch to the ipa user again
- `su test5`
- Now you should be prompted - *Please enter LDAP password + OTP
  token value:*
- Try logging in with password only. The attempt should fail.
- Attempt to switch to the ipa user once more
- `su test5`
- You should be prompted - *Please enter LDAP password + OTP
  token value:*
- Try logging in again with the password + OTP token value. (I used
  Google Authenticator to generate the token value). Login should be
  successful

I next tested from the OpenVPN client – with and without the OTP token.

Everything worked!

Comment: there is a bug https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1749279 about the need for the second prompting section.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is being tracked as a bug but the two new sections are reported out in the log file as 'not allowed'. I locally added them to [rule/allowed_sections] of cfg_rules.ini and then rebuilt and installed. The two new sections no longer show up in the log file as not allowed.